# Sending only push notifications to users on Microsoft Teams without bot messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am building a third party Microsoft Teams app and wanted to know if our app can trigger a push notification without it sending any actual messages to user through chat?

We have a chat tab for our app that we'd like to keep clean, and sending bot messages just as notifications to the user will make it cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

You can send proactive notification to user.

Could you please refer below doc for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: Hi @Nivedipa-MSFT, this proactive notification looks like a proactive bot message. Is there way for a push notification/pop-up to go through without having a bot message?

Comment: @hello12345 - using incoming webhook you can send notification to user.
Refer below document for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook